# Java OOP case for object type answer

Tags: java, android, oop

I have this simple oop case and wondering what is the best practise to implement / design my classes:

```
public class AnswerString {
   String answer;
}

public class AnswerInteger {
   int answer;
}

public class AnswerBoolean {
   boolean answer;
}
```

I need to combinate this class in single one and use it in array adapter, array list, sqlite db etc...

```
public interface / abstract class Answer {
   ???
   getAnswer()
}
```

Comment: generics ? `public abstract class Answer<T> { public abstract T getAnswer(); }`

Comment: @Blackbelt In fact it wouldn't have to be abstract anymore then, right?

Comment: @Fildor it is not necessary, I agree .

Comment: What is Answer used for?

Comment: answer is used to handling different question answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to create Answer class and store your value as Object along with class type (String, Integer, Boolean), or use generics